# How to get total send count for individual email in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to get total send count for indiviual email in marketing cloud? I'm thinking of querying the _Sent data view; however, it does not have the Email ID, or Email Name i can leverage to use inside a query?

So far - i've the Email Name and External Key.

Any idea on how to solve this challenge?

Comment: You will need to join the `_sent` data view with `_jobs` to get the "Email ID".

Comment: @DeploymentFailure - Thank you for your input. What do you think of this query:                   SELECT COUNT (s.JobID) AS Send_Count
FROM _Sent s
INNER JOIN _Job j
ON s.JobID = j.JobID
WHERE j.EmailID = '221125'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query you posted in the comment will work:

```
SELECT COUNT (s.JobID) AS Send_Count FROM _Sent s INNER JOIN _Job j ON s.JobID = j.JobID 
WHERE j.EmailID = '221125'
```

I wanted to propose something similar, which will give the same result:

```
SELECT COUNT (SubscriberKey) AS SENT_COUNT FROM _Sent
WHERE JobID IN (SELECT JobID FROM _Job WHERE EmailID = '221125')
```

From the performance standpoint, the second query was a little bit faster when I tested.

Please note, that this will only count the number of times this email has been sent in the last 6 months - if you would like to get a total count since the email creation, you would have to use API instead of SQL.

Comment: Thanks much! How'd i use API for that? I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: There’s no easy answer to that.. if you’re not familiar with SFMC API, you can start with this Trailhead module: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-apis

Comment: Will do - thank you for your help. I've also found that you can get the email send count using the Email Performance Over Time Report or the Impression Tracking For Triggered Send by Period in Analytics Builder in SFMC. :)